# How can I store special unicode characters in a char variable (c++)

Tags: c++, ascii

I am writing a c++ program, in which I need to store the value of a **special ASCII character**(eg:-'①','╳','▲',etc.) in a character variable like :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    char a = '①';//here...
    cout << a;

    return 0;
}
```

...and it throws errors saying

```
warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
```

and

```
warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
```

Is there any way to do this ???

Comment: These *aren't* ASCII characters. Use a wide character: `wchar_t a = L'①';` You'll, of course, need to print it to `wcout`.

Comment: Simple answer is: You can't. Either use strings to store the "character" as a string (e.g. `std::string a = "①";`) or use a wide-character type (as in `wchar_t`, `char16_t` or `char32_t`).

Comment: Please note: One thing is the right encoding of the characters. The other thing is that the encoding must be supported by the output console (and its font must support appropriate glyphs for the encoding). [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the wide character datatype, as it can store ASCII as well as non-ASCII characters in C++, which is represented by `wchar_t`.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    wchar_t a = L'';
    wcout << a;
    return 0;
}
```

As shown above, the smiley character gets stored in `a`. Since it involves wide character(s), to display it to console, I have to use `std::wcout`. Similarly, `std::wcin` is the wide character alternative for `std::cin` and `std::wstring` for `std::string`.

The `L` prefix is used to represent wide characters and wide strings. Here, it is used to tell the compiler that  is a wide character.